# TensorFlow: What is the purpose of checking for stops in a Supervisor Managed Session?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I've just read the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/supervisor#supervisor_reference) here again, and it says the supervisor needs to explicitly check for the stop condition in the main loop, but it doesn't explain why it has to do so. What's the reason behind it?

So far for most of my code I've not included this condition and things still work fine. Is there a case I should be worried about here?

Also, if the condition is a standard code like:

```
if sv.should_stop():
    sv.request_stop()
```

that has to be included every time a session was run, why couldn't it be included in a managed session by default? Meaning to say, is there a special use for writing this code explicitly in the for/while loop for training?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is in case one of your queues becomes empty, or something else errors out and requires you to stop. If your queues are never empty and there are never any errors then you don't need to check.

Comment: Is that to say if I prevent my queues from being empty by having a sufficient buffer amount in my queue, I wouldn't need to check for stops at all? What would be the difference between having the supervisor stop and having an error that forces it to stop?

Comment: If you're doing distributed training you might need to stop because of remote failures, but otherwise I think you're right, and there is no difference that matters.

Comment: That's a very good point! I've not had the chance to do distributed training unfortunately, so I'll keep that in mind when I do get the opportunity to do so. Thank you! :D